# Equation comments/conditions aligned to the far right

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, comments, tags

I'd like to move unnumbered equation comments or conditions to the *far right* of the equation, just like a flushright environment would do, but of course the environment can't work inside of the equation, neither if I put it in a \tag{} or a \rlap{} argument.
Here's a very simple (and not working) starting point, with the condition close to the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
    a+b=c {\ c>0}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

I know the condition should be closer to the equation than what I'm trying to do, but still I'd like to solve the issue this way, without using \quad or any other way of just distancing equation and condition..

Comment: you say not `\tag` but doesn't that do exactly what you want?  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[
    a+b=c \tag{$c>0$}
    \]  
\end{document}` (or `\tag*` if you don't want (...)  )

Comment: You're right in not wanting to abuse `\tag`. But a condition such as c>0 is *part of the equation*, so there's no reason for moving it far from the rest.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \tag gives me some issues: if I want to explicit a comment to the far of a line in an aligned environment tag would just end at the center of the lines block. Also it would shift the single line equation to the left

Comment: @egreg you're surely right, the condition should stay close to the equation being part of it, but sometimes I'd like to explicit what is happening between different lines of an aligned environment to the far right, to clarify the procedure

Comment: in an aligned you can simply use `&` to get to the next right aligned column